# How is Animal Rebellion connected to the Extinction Rebellion (XR) movement?

Tags: outreach, environment

I’ve been seeing news about the extinction rebellion (XR) movement from several countries lately, and I’ve also been seeing news about Animal Rebellion, mostly from England and Australia. Are these movements connected? Do they have the same demands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They appear aligned, in that AR posts are in the same style and hosted on the same site as the XR events, e.g.: https://rebellion.earth/event/october-animal-rebellion/

About goals, they have overlapping goals. "Animal Rebellion is an animal and climate justice movement with the stated aim of using nonviolent civil disobedience to compel government action towards a plant-based food system." (Wikipedia). XR's demands are shared by several other groups, including AR: https://rebellion.earth/the-truth/demands/

So, they are more overlapping than not, but still distinct.